# How to resolve emoji-codes :wave: into emojis in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, emoji

I would like to resolve the common emoji codes like ":wave:" or ":+1:" into the actual emoji-pictures.

Is there an easy and fast way to do this in Angular/HTML/ts/js without slicing the string?

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the [NPM package](https://typectrl.github.io/ngx-emoji-mart/) Namindu suggested and implemented a pipe to translate texts including emoji-codes to display the emojis instead of the code, because the package is just providing an emoji-picker.

```
export class EmojiTranslatePipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(private emojiService: EmojiService) {
  }

  transform(value: string, args?: any): string {
    let subs = value.split(":");
    subs.forEach(s => {
      let emoji = this.findEmoji(s);
      if (emoji) {
        let emojiCode = `:${s}:`;
        value = value.replace(emojiCode, emoji);
      }
    });
    return value;
  }

  findEmoji(id: string): string | undefined {
    let emoji = this.emojiService.emojis.find(emoji => emoji.id == id);
    if (emoji) {
      return emoji.native;
    }
    return undefined;
  }

}
```

Comment: Its looks like my answer helped for you. Please upvoted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try with [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ctrl/ngx-emoji-mart) NPM package. it might be help for you.